# ModuleNotFound error with django + gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a django project using this [tutorial](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html) as a guide. I am getting a "ModuleNotFoundError". What am I dong wrong? (see attached)

I don't know if its worth mentioning that when I run-

`gunicorn portal.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

or

`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/CleanBoy portal.wsgi`

it works fine. (`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/CleanBoy portal.wsgi` seems to respond faster) but when I call the batch file (`./gunicorn_start.bash`) in step 6. (from jee-appy.blogspot.com/) I get the error below. Please help. 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the procfile you are using for Heroku?

Comment: I am doing this on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver.

Comment: Do you have a deploy script or you are running the commands manually?

Comment: I am following along with the tutorial. So just manually.